# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver;)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am writing jax-rs restful application using jersey(, GET request was fine but POST, PUT & DELETE request give the error below

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/RESTful_JaxRS] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver;)V] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver;)V
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.setProperty(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:562)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone answer what jar do I need to include or what is the solution?

Comment: Throw your code here and we will see a big picture.

Comment: What version of eclipselink library are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright so problem is with `eclipselink` version.
Propably you are using the latest one `2.6`.
This error means that in above version class `XMLUnmarshaller` doesn't have that method.
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver`

What i see from this site: http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/
Only version from `2.42` to `2.5.2` has that method.

So my conclusion is to downgrade your `eclipselink` lib version to `2.5.2`.

At least give a shot and check the results.

Comment: I downgraded the jars with org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.4.2.jar & org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.4.2.jar and it works....thanks