# Java Jersey REST NoSuchMethodError: XMLUnmarshaller

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, glassfish

I create a small REST API and I have problem with POST method where consume and produce `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. When I send POST server (GlassFish 4.1.1) returns the status code 500 Internal Server Error as well as the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver;)V
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423037/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-eclipse-persistence-oxm-xmlunmarshaller-setname) and changed the version `org.eclipse.persistance.moxy`. It don't resolve my problem.

I use Maven and my dependency actually looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Edit.
It is sample code of POST method:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;  

@Path("/adverts")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AdvertsResources {

@POST
public void addAdvert(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                      @Valid final Advert advert,
                      @Context final UriInfo uriInfo) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            asyncResponse.resume(doAddAdvert(advert, uriInfo));
        }
    });
}

private Response doAddAdvert(@Valid Advert advert,
                             @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    Advert newAdvert = advertService.addAdvert(advert);
    String newId = String.valueOf(newAdvert.getId());
    URI newUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newId).build();

    return Response.created(newUri)
            .entity(newAdvert)
            .build();
}
}
```

@EDIT

Hello,

I resolve my problem with JSON and POST method. What I do:

1) Change GlassFish 4.1.1 to GlassFish 4.1

2) Add dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at code and complete stack, it is very difficult to pinpoint the problem, but the root cause for **[`NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)**
is most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class
>   (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition
>   of that method.

So, verify the list of libraries and their versions (specially `eclipselink`) while compilation and at deployed server.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am trying recompile all class and change dependency but it still does not work. I edit my first post and add some sample code of POST method.

Comment: @atezor Please note, `NoSuchMethodError` is a `Error` that means it will only occur during runtime. So, you need to make sure, you have same library (even their version) at runtime.